# show Hashmap list values in primefaces datatable rowwise

Tags: primefaces

I want to show `HashMap<Integer, List<C>>` values in PrimeFaces datatable . All values of the map should list rowwise per key. i.e. key1 values should be in 1st column, key2 values in 2nd column and so on..

so far, I have the list and values in columnwise. i.e key1 in first column, key1 values in 2nd column

Comment: Hi, did you follow the http://stackoverflow.com/tour? And read [ask]? Does it work with plain jsf?

Comment: And please correct your question. You state rowwise and then immediately speak about columns. And I assume you checked the PrimeFaces DataTable Showcase for solutions? http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/subTable.xhtml